# jwilder/nginx-proxy and cloudflare got error 500 when request with https

Tags: docker, https, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm having problem with using jwilder/nginx-proxy with cloudflare ssl (origin key)

Everything is working fine (in http) but I've got error 500 (in https)

[image]

reverse proxy

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - private:/etc/nginx/private
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

volumes:
  certs:
  private:
  private:
  nginx-conf:

    

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name:
        webproxy
```

lemp container

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    container_name: lemp_php
    build: php/
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./html/:/var/www/html
    expose:
      - "9000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  nginx:
    container_name: lemp_nginx
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    
    networks:
      - webproxy
      - default

    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: certbot.xxxxxx.net
      VIRTUAL_PROTO: https
    
    volumes:
      - ./html/:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
      - ../nginx_proxy_dock/certs:/etc/ssl/certs
    expose:
      - "80"
      - "443"
      

  db:
    container_name: lemp_mariadb
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./mariadb/initdb/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./mariadb/data/:/var/lib/mysql/

    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxxx
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=xxxxx
      - MYSQL_USER=xxxxxx
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=xxxxxx

  pma:
    container_name: lemp-phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always

    networks:
      - webproxy
      - default

    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: http_test.xxxxxx.net
    
    expose:
        - "80"
        - "443"


networks:
  default:
    external:
      name:
        web_network
  webproxy:
    external:
      name: webproxy
```

when I called

> https://certbot.xxxxxx.net:2053

I've got error 500 Internal Server Error

but when I called

> http://http_test.xxxxxx.net:8080

It's ok

Comment: Have you figured this issue out? I am running into something similar.